# Unable to predict the pop up apperaence

Tags: java, selenium, popup, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing a issue regarding a popup(not a browser popup an application one), and im handling it perfectly. But the problem is i dont know when it appears and by default i'm using Thread.sleep for 20 seconds in order to handle it. Now i have to cut down the time and have to handle the issue effectively.Can any one pls help me out without using Thread.sleep.

Thread.sleep(20000);

```
    if(oASelFW.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsrFloatingMid']")).isDisplayed()){
        oASelFW.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='fsrCloseBtn']")).click();
}
```

Comment: You can use webdriverwait class and wait for the element to appear using expected condition method. Also if you have declared implicit wait then by default the script waits for the element to appear. Let me know if you want further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of [Explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) which will allow to wait until certain condition is satisfied - which in your case is until is element present.

```
WebElement whatever = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
        By.xpath("//div[@class='fsrFloatingMid']"));
```